# 2CheckOut - Error : Bad Request - Parameter error

Tags: php, laravel, payment-gateway, 2checkout

**Request Data to TwoCheckOut :**

[image: Request Data]

**Response from TwoCheckOut.**

```
{
    "error": "Bad request - parameter error"
}
```

**Here is the Code**

```
     $charge = Twocheckout_Charge::auth(array(
            "sellerId" => '*HIDDEN*',
            "merchantOrderId" => $orderID,
            "token"      => $token,
            "currency"   => $currency,
            "total"      => $itemPrice,
            "billingAddr" => array(
                "name" => $name,
                "addrLine1" => $addrLine1,
                "city" => $city,
                "state" => $state,
                "zipCode" => $zipCode,
                "country" => $country,
                "email" => $email,
                "phoneNumber" => $phoneNumber
            ),
            "shippingAddr" => array(
            "name" => 'Testing Tester',
            "addrLine1" => '123 Test St',
            "city" => 'Columbus',
            "state" => 'OH',
            "zipCode" => '43123',
            "country" => 'USA',
            "email" => 'testingtester@2co.com',
            "phoneNumber" => '555-555-5555'
            ),
            "demo" => true

        ));
```

Althought i am getting **unauthenticated** if i send wrong 'token' key.

***EDIT :***

**MY VIEW JS CODE**
[image: front end code]

Feel free to drop your suggestions

Comment: have a look those answer,may be those can help you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25227500/2checkout-bad-request-parameter-error

Comment: All the answers are quite old and 2checkout recently updated their libraries and reworked on their flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"demo" => 'Y'
```

Demo key should be 'Y' not true was the issue here

Answer (score 0):

```
TCO.loadPubKey('production');
```

loadPubKey should be 'production' it should not be empty